# I can't hibernate my PC!

Tags: swap, hibernate, ubuntu-netbook

this is my first time asking because I finally found a problem that I cannot solve googling. The thing is that after expanding my swap partition (from 2gb to 4gb) my Vivid Ubuntu can't pm-hibernate/ suspend/ suspend-hybrid. At least before expanding the swap it tried to run these commands but even in "normal functionality", rebooting the PC it just started the greeter as if I never hibernated it. I don't know what to do or what I've done (I'm not a pro user... Yet... I'm slowly learning ok?) if someone could help me it would be great.